# changing font colors using css while using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am learning bootstrap but I am wondering if I can change the colors of fonts while using bootstrap at the same time. Right now, I am trying to change the font color of my nav-links in my Navbar but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.container-fluid{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-item{
    color: violet;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">



<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#uniqueIdentifier">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div id="uniqueIdentifier" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  </header>
```

Comment: Try adding the style to the `.nav-link` class instead of the `.nav-item` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specificity of a CSS rule depends on the selectors. The more specific a CSS selector is, the higher will be its precedence. The default colour is being applied from these classes  `.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link`. In order to override it using classes, a three-level deep selector needs to be defined.

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: violet;
}
```

Or else if you want to use only a single selector,  `!important` property can be used with it.

```
.nav-link {
    color: violet !important;
}
```